Is there any evolution going on in L3 layer
In application layer, there're HTTP 2 & 3. In L4 it's QUIC. In lower layers there're various wired & wireless standards.
What about L3? Is there any speed improvement in transition from IPv4 to IPv6? Or this layer doesn't provide any speed improvement at all?

Internet's L3 (IP) only deals with inter-network addressing and routing of individual packets – it leaves decisions like congestion control to the upper protocols (e.g. TCP) and packet queuing/buffering to the underlying lower networks (e.g. algorithms such as CoDeL that are developed independently of IP) – so it has very little influence on "speed" overall.
There may be some minor differences due to the reduced need for NAT (although that was not originally part of IPv4 either; it was a much later addition), or due to smaller routing tables; and a new network protocol means new routing tables, interconnections, etc., so IPv6 might be "slower" or "faster" just because it takes a different path from A to B due to mismatching configurations; but that's not inherent in the protocols.
Evolution still happens, but for other reasons than speed; e.g. the addressing has evolved from 32-bit addresses in IPv4 to 128-bit in IPv6, and the IP-adjacent protocols such as BGP do keep receiving occasional improvements. (BGP deals with inter-network routing, so it's functionally part of the same layer as IP.)
As an inter-network protocol, though, IP (and BGP) is in a position where it's really hard to replace it with something new – unlike local networks that can be replaced easily, or higher protocols that only matter end-to-end (for the most part), IP is something that everything in the path has to care about – for example, we're currently 28 years into replacing IPv4 with IPv6 and still not even halfway done.
Similarly, there have been attempts to improve on inter-network routing by replacing BGP with things like LISP (e.g. to reduce the massive IP routing tables that BGP operators deal with), but those are unlikely to find global adoption – even if it's an improvement in some ways.
